# Filter a list of strings by a char in same position

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, function

I am trying to make a simple function that gets three inputs: a list of words, list of guessed letters and a pattern. The pattern is a word with some letters hidden with an underscore. (for example the word apple and the pattern '_pp_e')
For some context it's a part of the game hangman where you try to guess a word and this function gives a hint.
I want to make this function to return a filtered list of words from the input that does not contain any letters from the list of guessed letters and the filtered words contain the same letters and their position as with the given pattern.
I tried making this work with three loops.

1. First loop that filters all words by the same length as the pattern.
2. Second loop that checks for similarity between the pattern and the given word. If the not filtered    word does contain the letter but not in the same position I filter it out.
3. Final loop checks the filtered word that it does not contain any letters from the given guessed list.

I tried making it work with not a lot of success, I would love for help. Also any tips for making the code shorter (without using third party libraries) will be a appreciated very much.
Thanks in advance!

Example: pattern: "d _ _ _ _ a _ _ _ _" guessed word list ['b','c'] and word list contain all the words in english.
output list: ['**d**eleg**a**ting', '**d**erog**a**tion', '**d**ishw**a**sher']

this is the code for more context:

```
def filter_words_list(words, pattern, wrong_guess_lst):
lst_return = []
lst_return_2 = []
lst_return_3 = []
new_word = ''
for i in range(len(words)):
    if len(words[i]) == len(pattern):
        lst_return.append(words[i])
pattern = list(pattern)
for i in range(len(lst_return)):
    count = 0
    word_to_check = list(lst_return[i])
    for j in range(len(pattern)):
        if pattern[j] == word_to_check[j] or (pattern[j] == '_' and
                                              (not (word_to_check[j] in
                                                    pattern))):
            count += 1
    if count == len(pattern):
        lst_return_2.append(new_word.join(word_to_check))
for i in range(len(lst_return_2)):
    word_to_check = lst_return_2[i]
    for j in range(len(wrong_guess_lst)):
        if word_to_check.find(wrong_guess_lst[j]) == -1:
            lst_return_3.append(word_to_check)

return lst_return_3
```

Comment: could you add an example of expected input and output?

Comment: Of course, I added an example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest, and likely quite efficient, way to do this would be to translate your pattern into a regular expression, if regular expressions are in your "toolbox". (The `re` module is in the standard library.)

In a regular expression, `.` matches any single character. So, we replace all `_`s with `.`s and add `"^"` and `"$"` to anchor the regular expression to the whole string.

```
import re

def filter_words(words, pattern, wrong_guesses):
    re_pattern = re.compile("^" + re.escape(pattern).replace("_", ".") + "$")
    
    # get words that 
    #   (a) are the correct length 
    #   (b) aren't in the wrong guesses 
    #   (c) match the pattern
    return [
        word
        for word in words
        if (
            len(word) == len(pattern) and
            word not in wrong_guesses and
            re_pattern.match(word)
        )
    ]

all_words = [
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "mouse",
    "horse",
    "cow",
]

print(filter_words(all_words, "c_t", []))
print(filter_words(all_words, "c__", []))
print(filter_words(all_words, "c__", ["cat"]))
```

prints out

```
['cat']
['cat', 'cow']
['cow']
```

If you *don't* care for using regexps, you can instead translate the pattern to a dict mapping each defined position to the character that should be found there:

```
def filter_words_without_regex(words, pattern, wrong_guesses):
    # get a map of the pattern's defined letters to their positions
    letter_map = {i: letter for i, letter in enumerate(pattern) if letter != "_"}
    # get words that
    #   (a) are the correct length
    #   (b) aren't in the wrong guesses
    #   (c) have the correct letters in the correct positions
    return [
        word
        for word in words
        if (
            len(word) == len(pattern) and
            word not in wrong_guesses and
            all(word[i] == ch for i, ch in letter_map.items())
        )
    ]
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Hi! Why you used `re.escape`?

Comment: Just in case the pattern contains other metacharacters that should be escaped for regexp use.

Comment: ok but from the doc _This function must not be used for the replacement string in sub() and subn(), only backslashes should be escaped._. I don't want to stress you... just find it quite confusing

Comment: Well, I'm not using it for `.sub()` or `.subn()` :)

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot for the answer it really helped. I can't use the re library so I gotta with the second version. thanks a lot it really helps to learn from others as a CS student where I still write long and inefficient code!

Comment: Another thing theirs a problem with the func without regex where it still returns words that may have a letter from the given pattern but not in the same position. For example: input pattern "_ _ a _ _ _ i _" and the output list is ['abattoir', 'Brasilia', 'headship']

Comment: Those seem like correct outputs..?

Comment: Almost but not quite. For example the pattern  "_ _ a _ _ _ i _" will filter out any words that contain words with the letter "a" in a different position. So the word 'abattoir' should be filtered out but  'headship' is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient, but this should work:

```
def filter_words_list(words, pattern, wrong_guess_lst):
    fewer_words = [w for w in words if not any([wgl in w for wgl in wrong_guess_lst])]
    equal_len_words = [w for w in fewer_words if len(w) == len(pattern)]
    pattern_indices = [idl for idl, ltr in enumerate(pattern) if ltr != '_']
    word_indices = [[idl for idl, ltr in enumerate(w) if ((ltr in pattern) and (ltr != '_'))] for w in equal_len_words]
    out = [w for wid, w in zip(word_indices, equal_len_words) if ((wid == pattern_indices) and (w[pid] == pattern[pid] for pid in pattern_indices))]
    return out
```

The idea is to first remove all words that have letters in your `wrong_guess_lst`.
Then, remove everything which does not have the same length (you could also merge this condition in the first one..).
Next, for both pattern and your remaining words, you create a pattern mask, which indicates the positions of non `'_'` letters.
To be a candidate, the masks have to be identical AND the letters in these positions have to be identical as well.

Note, that I replaced a lot of for loops in you code by list comprehension snippets. List comprehension is a very useful construct which helps a lot especially if you don't want to use other libraries.

Edit: I cannot really tell you, where your code went wrong as it was a little too long for me..

Comment: Thanks a Lot the code worked for me! The answer from AKX  was a bit more efficient and easier to understand thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

The regex rule is *explicitely* constructed, in particular no check on the word's length is needed. To achieve this the `groupby` function from the `itertools` package of the standard library is used:

`'_ b _ _ _'` -- regex-- > `r'^.{1}b.{3}$'`

Here how to filter the dictionary by a guess string:

```
import itertools as it
import re

# sample dictionary
dictionary = "a ability able about above accept according account across act action activity actually add address"
dictionary = dictionary.split()

guess = '_ b _ _ _'
guess = guess.replace(' ', '') # remove white spaces

# construction of the regex rule
regex = r'^'
for _, i in it.groupby(guess, key=lambda x: x == '_'):
    if '_' in (l:=list(i)):
        regex += ''.join(f'.{{{len(l)}}}') # escape the curly brackets
    else:
        regex += ''.join(l)
regex += '$'

# processing the regex rule
pattern = re.compile(regex)

# filter the dictionary by the rule
l = [word for word in dictionary if pattern.match(word)]
print(l)
```

Output

```
['about', 'above']
```